# Flutter Android TV app Google Play rejection

Tags: android, flutter, television

I have developed flutter tv app and uploaded to Google pay store it's keep getting rejected , attached image rejection reason [image]

Comment: Have you tried your app in real android tv? Have you added leanback?

Comment: I have tested its working running in more than 10 TV currently

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I am glad that I'm seeing another person developing app for android tv. Before I also had this problem, but after a while I realized that I forgot to add some lines of code in xml files.

Here are some steps for you to do.

1.set minSdkVersion to 21 or higher in project/android/app/build.gradle

2.Declare separate activity in project/android/app/src/main/androidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"                    
    /> 
  </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

3.Add this line in *Project/android/app/src/main/androidmanifest.xml* above application tag to declare that your app uses leanback user interface:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
  android:required="false" />
```

4.Add this line below previous one:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
          android:required="false" />
```

5.provide Home Screen icon and Home Screen banner inside application tag:

```
<application
...
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:banner="@drawable/image_name_in_drawable_folder" >
...
</application>
```

if you already have these lines then go to android/src/main/res and there are drawable and mipmap folders. mipmap folders are for the app icon and drawable folder is only tv banner if I'm not mistaken. And the banner(drawable) should have the size of 320 x 180 px.

6.Change the launcher color. Go to android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml and inside style tag with name LaunchTheme, add these lines:

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
```

I think now your application should be accepted in android tv store by Google play.

In addition: Here is the link to android developers tv guide page if you want to see original android developers guide for tv apps:
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start

P.S: All of these steps are required if you haven't already done even one of them your application will continue to get rejected. Then don't forget to add image in android/app/src/main/res/drawable